# Lisp: ordered union of two lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, union

I am trying to make a function that returns the union of two lists in an ordered manner.
Here is my code:

```
(defun setunion (lst1 lst2)
  (cond
    ((null lst1) lst2)
    ((null lst2) lst1)
    ((member (car lst2) lst1)
     (setunion lst1 (cdr lst2)))
    (t (append (setunion lst1 (cdr lst2))
               (list (car lst2))))))


(print (setunion '(a b c) '(a c d e f a)))
```

This returns (A B C F E D) but the output I am looking for is (A B C D E F). How can I change my code to return the right output?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I figured it out I think. I made a helper function that removes the duplicates of list 2 and reverses it as well as remove the duplicates of list 1.

```
(defun help (lst1 lst2)
(setunion (remove-duplicates lst1 :from-end t) (reverse(remove-duplicates lst2 :from-end t))))
(print (help  '(b c b d) '(a d e a)))
```

This gives me the output (B C D A E) which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: your second list in your example is not ordered. If you want ordered output you would need to add them in some particular way or sort the result. Operations might want to look at are comparison functions, 'merge', 'sort' or similar.

Comment: Note that appending the single element at the end is very inefficient *and* will reverse the order of the elements you append.

Comment: Your second list has duplicate elements.  What should the output of `(setunion '(b c d) '(a d e a))` be?

Comment: If you want an ordered object you must have a function which defines the order, which you don't have.

Comment: The output of (setunion '(b c d) '(a d e a)) should be (B C A E)

Comment: Hm? Where did `d` go?

Comment: Yeah sorry there's a d missing, it should be (B C D A E).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so basically all you want to do is remove duplicates over all lists, and the elements should be in order of first appearance.  You could append all lists, then remove duplicates from the end:

```
(defun set-union (&rest lists)
  (remove-duplicates (reduce #'append lists)
                     :from-end t))
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the union of a bunch of lists such that elements in the lists occur in the order they occur in the lists, working from the left, then here is one fairly natural way of doing that.  I'm not sure if this is what I'd write in real life.  It has the advantage that:

- it's easy to see what is happening;
- it doesn't rely on hairy standard CL functions.

It has the *disadvantage* that it requires tail-call elimination to work with long lists (and some people regard code which works like this not to be idiomatic CL).

```
(defun union-preserving-order (&rest ls)
  ;; Union of a bunch of lists.  The result will not contain
  ;; duplicates (under EQL) and elements will occur in the order they
  ;; occur in the lists, working from the left to the right.  So
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(a b) '(b a c)) will be (a b c), as will
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(a b) '(c b a)), while
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(b a) '(a b c) '(c d)) will be (b a c
  ;; d).
  (upo/loop (first ls) (rest ls) '()))

(defun upo/loop (lt more accum)
  ;; LT is the list we're working on, MORE is more lists for later,
  ;; ACCUM is the list we're building (backwards). In real life this
  ;; would be a local function in UNION-PRESERVING-ORDER.
  (if (null lt)
      ;; Finished this list
      (if (null more)
          ;; no more lists: we're done
          (nreverse accum)
        ;; more lists, so pick the first of them and loop on that
        (upo/loop (first more) (rest more) accum))
    ;; not finished this list, so loop on it
    (upo/loop (rest lt) more
              ;; Either the next element of this list is already in
              ;; the accumulator, or it's not and we need to add it.
              (if (member (first lt) accum)
                  accum           
                (cons (first lt) accum)))))
```

Here's a version which uses explicit iteration but otherwise does the same trick.

```
(defun union-preserving-order (&rest ls)
  ;; Union of a bunch of lists.  The result will not contain
  ;; duplicates (under EQL) and elements will occur in the order they
  ;; occur in the lists, working from the left to the right.  So
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(a b) '(b a c)) will be (a b c), as will
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(a b) '(c b a)), while
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(b a) '(a b c) '(c d)) will be (b a c
  ;; d).
  (let ((accum '()))
    (dolist (l ls (nreverse accum))
      (dolist (e l)
        (pushnew e accum)))))
```

Finally here's a dirty hack which builds the results forwards.  Without proof I think this is as good as you can do in terms of performance without resorting to some clever lookup structure like a hash-table to check whether you've seen elements already.

```
(defun union-preserving-order (&rest ls)
  ;; Union of a bunch of lists.  The result will not contain
  ;; duplicates (under EQL) and elements will occur in the order they
  ;; occur in the lists, working from the left to the right.  So
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(a b) '(b a c)) will be (a b c), as will
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(a b) '(c b a)), while
  ;; (union-preserving-order '(b a) '(a b c) '(c d)) will be (b a c
  ;; d).
  (let ((results '())                   ;results we'll return
        (rlc nil))                      ;last cons of results
    (dolist (l ls results)
      (dolist (e l)
        (unless (member e results)
          (if (not (null rlc))
              (setf (cdr rlc) (list e)
                    rlc (cdr rlc))
            (setf rlc (list e)
                  results rlc)))))))
```